# C and OpenCV memory leaks

Tags: c, opencv, memory-leaks

I have problem with memory leaks. In this simple program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int main() {
    CvMat *src;
    src = cvLoadImageM("p1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cvSaveImage("p2.bmp", src, 0);  
    cvReleaseMat(&src);
    return 0;
}
```

According to valgrind, there are 7 leaks:

```
==10478== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10478==     in use at exit: 10,464 bytes in 7 blocks
==10478==   total heap usage: 154 allocs, 147 frees, 2,908,450 bytes allocated
==10478== 
==10478== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10478==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10478==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10478==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10478==    still reachable: 10,464 bytes in 7 blocks
==10478==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10478== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==10478== 
==10478== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10478== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Can anybody tell me how to properly free memory? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You didn't demonstrate that you have a memory leak, only that valgrind complains of one. Complex libraries sometimes use allocation patterns that are misreported as leaks by tools like valgrind. (Example include allocation pools, or not running destructors at exit for performance reasons.) A simple way to test whether you're dealing with a real memory leak or not is to wrap the entire contents of `main()` (except for the `return` statement) in an infinite loop. Start the process and observe it using `top` or equivalent tool: if its memory grows without bounds, *then* you have a leak on hand.

Answer (score 1):

@user4815162342 is probably right.
Though I recommend you migrate to new `C++` `OpenCv` `cv::Mat` through which memory management is automatic.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this leak many times. Check the detailed errors above what you sent. It's probably the pixman lib.